# Online estimation of drifting discrete probability

Tags: time-series, estimation, online-algorithms

I recently come across (in a practical setting) to the following problem. Suppose I receive items from a finite set ,one at a time . At each moment one item is drawn independently from an unknown probability distribution. The probability distribution changes over time, but we can bound the rate of change (e.g. using KL divergence or something similar ). At each moment t (assume t is also discrete), using only these assumptions and the observations made so far ,we want to estimate the current probabilities over the set of items.

A bit more formal now. If our set of items is $S=\{1,2,..,n\}$
at each moment $t∈N$, we have a probability measure over S, $p(t,i),i∈S$ that we want to estimate . Let C be a fixed constant such that $KL(p(t−1,.),p(t,.))≤C,∀t∈N$ (KL- Kullback–Leibler divergence , but other "distance" concepts are good enough).At each time t, based on the set of t observations $\{o_{1},o_{2},o_{3},...o_{t}\},∀i=1...t,o_{i}∈S$ (at each time step we made one observation) we want to estimate the current probabilities $p(t,1),p(t,2),...,p(t,n)$

Is this a known problem in statistics/probability ? Any relevant textbooks/papers will be appreciated .

P.S - I posted the same question on math.stackexchange.com, but I did not get any answer. Now I have deleted the question on math.stackexchange.com .

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2947156/14578, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/370893/2921, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/42301/5038.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.  If you decide you posted on the wrong site, you can delete your question before posting it elsewhere.